# Joomla 1.6 Component Tutorial

Tags: joomla, joomla-extensions, joomla1.6

Aside from the HelloWorld Tutorial, are there any other tutorials/books available with regards to component development on Joomla 1.6 ?

Although the HelloWorld guides the user through chapters/steps, it doesn't exactly explain what certain code or function does. I'm at [Part 14](http://docs.joomla.org/Developing_a_Model-View-Controller_%28MVC%29_Component_for_Joomla!1.6_-_Part_14), and I'm at a complete lost.

Really appreciate if someone could point me to some other tutorial sites or books to purchase..

Comment: How familiar are you with PHP? The tutorial you are referring to assumes you have a pretty good knowledge of both PHP and the basics of Joomla and how the ACL works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the Joomla Programming book by Mark Dexter, I am not sure whether its available yet.

[http://www.amazon.com/Joomla-Programming-Press-Mark-Dexter/dp/013278081X](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/013278081X)

you can see the preview here: http://my.safaribooksonline.com/book/web-development/joomla/9780132780841/components-part-ii-views-jform-and-front-end/ch08#X2ludGVybmFsX0ZsYXNoUmVhZGVyP3htbGlkPTk3ODAxMzI3ODA4NDEvMjE0

Answer (score 1):

Kyle,

Documentation supporting Joomla 1.6 is lacking at this time from what I've seen.  Your best bet might be http://learn.theartofjoomla.com/version-16-development.html.

This set of tutorials is exactly what is needed to really learn the new classes in 1.6. Unfortunately, they only take you so for to date.  Other videos are forthcoming according to Andrew Eddie.

I now of no other tutorial that will, at this time, take you completely through the process with thorough explanations.

Regards